# benefits of a wifi-6 AP with wifi-5 clients

Tags: wireless-networking

I am considering replacing my wifi-5 (ac) access point with a wifi-6 (ax) one, for a home with about 20 connected clients.

Several of these clients use the internet concurrently, including streaming video / video calls.

**My question - would a wifi-6 AP be able to better support the concurrent needs of these clients which are wifi-5, not wifi-6?**

I have read the following elsewhere - but am not sure how accurate or beneficial they are:

- wifi6 AP's are 4x4 minimum over wifi5's 2x2, to support more concurrent data streams
- wifi6 uses OFDM for more granular time-slicing, reducing latency
- wifi6 uses better beam forming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wifi-5 clients will communicate with the wifi-6 AP using the wifi-5 protocol.

That means in particular:

- No OFDMA
- Concurrent data streams with all wifi-5 clients according to wifi-5 capabilities

That said, if you have a mix of wifi-6 and wifi-5 clients, you still may get better performance because the wifi-6 clients will get "less in the way" of the wifi-5 clients.

Also, any advancements in the beamforming hardware/firmware/number of antennas will also apply to the wifi-5 clients.

Finally, if you consider buying a new AP anyhow, upgrading it to the newest technology to be future proof is really a no-brainer, no matter if you get immediate benefits, or not.

Comment: thanks @dirkt - that is helpful. I am using the Fritzbox 7530 and am considering the 7530 AX .. but it seems that if most of my clients will be wifi-5 for 2-3 more years ... maybe a fritzbox 7590 with a larger "MIMO" multipliers 4x4 vs the AX with 2x2 2.4Ghz and 3x3 5Ghz is a better idea? Would love feedback on this.

Comment: Yes, I'd assume the 7590 with 4x4 to perform much better with many wifi-5 clients than the AX with 2x2. But there are so many details that can influence the actual performance that the only way to really find out is to test it in your location.